# How do you manually renew a certificate in AzureKeyValut

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault

We have a CA that is not supported by Azure KeyVault. We have created certificates and CSRs using KeyVault and submitted them successfully to the CA and imported the signed cert. We now have some certs that pre-date our use of KeyVault that are up for renewal. Our security team has had new signed certs issued by the CA. But when we import the original signed cert and private key (pfx format) and then try to import the new signed cert it fails with "Pending Certificate not found". What's to proper sequence of bring these certs into KeyVault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So going off the comment above I was able to get this to work.

```
#Password for the pfx file of the original cert
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '<UPDATETHIS>' -AsPlainText -Force

#import the orginal cert with private key
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'VaultName' -Name 'Certname' -FilePath 'PATHTOPFXFILE' -Password $password

#set the policy to allow key reuse if the CA will create a new signed cert from the existing CSR
Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -VaultName 'VaultName' -Name 'Certname' -ReuseKeyOnRenewal $true

#create a cert policy object from the existing cert
$certpolicy = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -VaultName 'VaultName' -Name 'Certname'

#create a pending cert operation, you can pull a new CSR from this if need be
$certificateOperation = Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'VaultName' -Name 'Certname' -CertificatePolicy $certpolicy 

#import the new signed cert into KeyVault for issuing
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'VaultName' -Name 'Certname' -FilePath 'PATHTONEWSIGNEDCERTINCRT'
```

Answer (score 1):

An Azure Key Vault certificate is a versioned object. When you create a new certificate, you are creating a new version. Each version of the certificate is conceptually composed of 2 parts - an asymmetric key, and a blob which ties that asymmetric key to an identity.

When you need to use your own CA, AKV generates an asymmetric key and returns the CSR to the user. The user then uses the CSR to obtain a certificate. This is true for every version of the certificate.

If you current version is expiring, you need to create a new version. You need to follow the same steps as you did when creating the first version. You can optionally choose to use the same asymmetric key when creating a new version.

Comment: That's the difference with these the first version was created before KeyVault certificates existed. So I can't follow the same process. The only options I see then 1) is to use OpenSSL to combine the private key with the new signed cert and then import that new pfx as an updated version or 2) have KeyVault issue a new CSR and submit it to the CA to generate a new signed cert from it.?